# How to make smaller Select component in React?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, inline-styles

I'm working on React's `Select` component and it's driving me.. a little bit crazy, I have to admit. I'm trying to create simple dropdown button (sometimes called `ComboBox`). Something like that (taken from GitHub Insights):

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<Select
  size="small"
  className={classes.select}
  value={seasonFilter}
  variant="outlined"
  onChange={handleChangeSeasonFilter}>
  <MenuItem value={"2016-17-Reg"}>2016-17-Reg</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={"2017-18-Reg"}>2017-18-Reg</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={"2018-19-Reg"}>2018-19-Reg</MenuItem>
  <MenuItem value={"2019-20-Reg"}>2019-20-Reg</MenuItem>
</Select>
```

The `Select` looks good, but it's big. Looks like this (after the item was selected, so it's highlighted):

[image]

I want to make it smaller, so it's height is 30px. So I tired:

`<Select size="small" ...`  - didn't work (nothing changed)

I tried applying class:

```
select: {
  height: 30,
},

<Select className={classes.select}
```

It worked... kinda. It's smaller, but when I select it, the selected area is bigger. Like this (when highlighted):

[image]

How to remove that highlighted part?

BTW. It's not a margin/padding problem (I think). When I add two yellow `Box`es on above and under. These two grey things are still there (they are overlapping other components!):

[image]

Another test:

I changed the style class to this:

```
select: {
  height: 30,
  padding: 10,
},
```

I got this:

[image]

So I have a few questions actually:

- What is that strange grey thing??
- How to remove it?
- Why, when apply padding, only left and right padding changes, but not top and bottom?
- Last but not least, how to make `Select` smaller??

Answer (score 0):

go here: https://material-ui.com/api/select/#css

what u see over there, its the CSS classes applied right from the material ui, override them, USE "!important" to make sure style is applied.
hope it works, let me know :)

Comment: I'm using `useStyles()` and `className` parameter to apply styles. How can I change CSS directly?